# Add Custom Local Notification in ios10 - swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uilocalnotification, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to add a custom local notification, but I'm only getting the stock notification with my action:

[image]

My storyboard looks like this (standard template):

[image]

I have a extension which has `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` set to `awesomeNotification` (in Info.plist). Also the base of this extension is the `Notification Content` template from `iOS - Application Extension`.

In my app delegate I have this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let actions = [UNNotificationAction.init(identifier: "Hey", title: "Yo", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground)]

    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "awesomeNotification", actions: actions, minimalActions: actions, intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])

    center.requestAuthorization([.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    }

    return true
}
```

In my viewcontroller in the main app I have the following action to trigger it:

```
@IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.categoryIdentifier = "awesomeNotification"
    content.title = "Hello"
    content.body = "What up?"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the notification.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
    print("should have been added")
}
```

**Edit**

So it works on a iPhone 6s/6s+, very strange behaviour:
[image]

Comment: you mean you need custom view in notificaton right?

Comment: yes, thats what I'm trying to use.

Comment: i have been trying the same..but not able to show notification even in 6s?can you put your project in git?

Comment: I can see the custom green area only on 6s's

Comment: dont know why i am not able..bad luck..try harder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Update: As of iOS 10 beta 2, rich notifications are also available on pre-3D touch devices. Pull down on the regular notification to see it.***

Make sure you are testing on a iPhone6s/iPhone6s plus simulator/device, it doesn't seem to work on pre-3D touch devices.

On a iPhone6 simulator, try to click and drag down on the stock notification you get and you should see your custom UI appear.

Comment: That is so strange... I was expecting it to work on iPhone SE or even other devices, seems very strange to limit it to those. I was also expecting my content view to take over the view, but it still shows the stock below... oh well!

Comment: I was expecting the same and banged my head against the wall with this exact problem. Looks like it is coming to other models later: http://www.macrumors.com/2016/06/14/rich-notifications-without-3d-touch/